# Generate a function for an event

Tags: javascript, function, events

I want to generate functions for an event by using a loop. Surely in the example below, when pressing the button, it will gives the value 100 and not 1.

```html
    <body>
    <button id="b1">klickMeNow</button>
    <script>
      var i=1;
      document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function() { alert(i);}, false);
      var i=100;
      </script>        
    </body>
```

I came up with this solution using a generate function:

```html
    <button id="b1">klickMeNow</button>
    <script>
      var i=1;
      document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", generate(i), false);
      var i=100;   
        
      function generate(i1) {
        f =  function () {alert(i1);};
        return f;
      }
    </script>
```

Is there a more elegant solution without writing a generate function?

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly ?

Comment: Right, you probably don't need to do what you're trying to do. If you explain the problem in more we can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to for a simple counting function?

```js
var count = (function() {
  var c = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++c;
  }
}());

document.getElementById('b1').onclick = function() {
  alert(count());
}
```

```html
<button id="b1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: It'll output `function() {
    return ++c;
  }`

Comment: Forgot to wrap in self-executing function. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry for the confusion. 
If you run the first snippet it gives 100 as a result, but I want that it prints 1, the actual value when I bind the function.